# how to transfer data between persistant live usb and computer

Tags: persistence

I am using persistent ubuntu live usb. how can i transfer data(images, .xlsx etc) from one computer to live usb stick and move that data to another computer?

Answer (score 0):

If there's still space in that usb stick, you could copy the data there. Usually with ubuntu live usb (I don't know with persistent mode) you can access the information in `/cdrom` directory which also have a link in `/media/$USERNAME`. Or else you could just connect another pen drive, an external hard disk, or maybe pass the information via ssh, upload it to a server, etc. You really have a lot of options.

Answer (score 0):

as fast respond i cold tell netcat but you should tell more from the network between those machines.
if you  don't have any network service installed (like smb, ftp, ssh) you can do the following.

in the computer where you want to receive(server) the file `nc -l -p 8080 > someFile`

-l (listening mode)
-p (port you can use any port, but you should check if ist open in your firewall)

and in the sender machine(client) use `nc -w 3 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 8080 < someFile`
-w (set the timeout you could set any other from 3)
the xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx its the ip from the computer you want to receive (server) the file 
8080 its the port (obviously you have to set the same port in both computers)
the file name should be the same to.

this is not a long term solution to file transfer. its a easy and fast solution for transfer a few files without install any Service Server (note the transaction will be on plain text , without any encryption )on those machines if you need more option like  [netcat transferfile guide](http://nakkaya.com/2009/04/15/using-netcat-for-file-transfers/)